# How do I set an icon folder for tablets only?

Tags: android

How to set icon folder for tablets only? My tablet is pulling icons from the mdpi folder instead of the HDPI. Is there anyway to tell if its android honeycomb, then use these icon folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android will automatically pull from the correct drawable folder depending on the density of the device. Your issue is that some tablets (not all) are actually xhdpi instead of hdpi, though I would think it would fall back to hdpi before mdpi.

**Edit:** On second thought, I think the more likely scenario is that your tablet is actually mdpi, as there actually aren't a lot of xhdpi devices. What tablet device are you using?

Comment: exactly..So i tried to do xdpi it still pulled from mdpi. i even tried to add v11 to the end. The tablet is a 1280x800 resolution. Acer Iconia

Comment: Looked around on the web a bit. Seems the Acer Iconia is roughly 150 dpi, which would make it an mdpi device.

Comment: Hmm i see, so what could i do to make it where the icons are different. i need the icons to be bigger on the tablet screen, than it would be on a regular mdpi cell phone screen

Comment: Okay so i added drawbale-large-mdpi and walla!

Comment: For reference, this is a good read when wanting to support a wide range of different devices: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)